# ASP.NET Error When Updating from Gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Could Someone please assist me with this simple error I have been struggling with for the last couple of hours?
I am at the point of just burning the laptop....

Error:
[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.]

Code:

```
  Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim ID As Label = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lbl_ID"), Label)
    Dim AID As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_AID"), TextBox)
    Dim ADesc As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_ADesc"), TextBox)
    Dim Status As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_Status"), TextBox)
    Dim ADate As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_ADate"), TextBox)
    Dim Category As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_Category"), TextBox)
    Dim Location As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_Location"), TextBox)
    Dim CCenter As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_CCenter"), TextBox)
    Dim Group As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_Group"), TextBox)
    Dim Life As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_Life"), TextBox)
    Dim BValue As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_BValue"), TextBox)
    Dim RRate As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_RRate"), TextBox)
    Dim RType As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txt_RType"), TextBox)
    con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    con.Open()

    Dim sqlString As String = "UPDATE Asset_Registry SET Asset_ID=@AID,Asset_Description=@ADesc,Status=@Status,Acquisition_Date=@ADate,Category=@Category,Location=@Location,Cost_Center=@CCenter,Group=@Group,Life=@Life,Book_Value=@BValue,Rental_Rate=@RRate,Rental_Type=@RType WHERE ID=@ID"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlString, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AID", AID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADesc", ADesc.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADate", ADate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCenter", CCenter.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", Group.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Life", Life.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BValue", BValue.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RRate", RRate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RType", RType.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    ShowData()
End Sub
```

Comment: Reserved word, delimit it!

Comment: print query and check. What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) in SQL Server, escape it with `[]`:

```
UPDATE Asset_Registry 
SET Asset_ID=@AID,
    Asset_Description=@ADesc,
    ...
    [Group]=@Group -- <-----
    ...
WHERE ID=@ID
```